# Did SWIFT DateFormatter.dateFormat formatting change?

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I recently noticed my DateFormatter is no longer working with am/pm format. Did Swift recently change "h" and "a" dateFormat symbols? Could it be another setting I may have recently changed and am not seeing?

```
let formatt = DateFormatter()
formatt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateDater = formatt.date(from:"2019-03-16 14:00:00")
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm a"
let string = formatter.string(from:dateDater!)
print("DateString",string)
```

Result: **DateString 03/16/19 14:00**

Comment: For me it is still showing DateString 03/16/19 02:00 PM

Comment: Did you change Settings > General > Date and Time > 24 hour Time?

Comment: Yes it totally depends on your Date and Time settings

Comment: For fixed date formats you need to set your date formatter locale to en_US_POSIX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you prevent it, formatting depends on the user Locale. So it all depends on your regional and date time settings, such as this one:

[image]

And this one:

[image]

For more info, read https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html